# Unity - Vimeo Player Prefab and scripts can't be loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine, vimeo

[Vimeo Player Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bozNK.png)

[Vimeo Player prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0qg9.png)

Hi,

I'm trying to use the Vimeo Player script in my project. I'm using Unity 2019.2.11f1 with AVPro 1.9.10 and for some reason, I'm getting some script errors:

Assets/Vimeo/Scripts/Recorder/RecorderController.cs(15,59): error CS0117: 'Path' does not contain a definition for 'GetTempPath'

Assets/Vimeo/Scripts/Recorder/RecorderController.cs(98,36): error CS0117: 'Path' does not contain a definition for 'Combine'

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: So you have a script you made called Path?

Comment: I don't. I'm using iTween libraries and there are some example scripts that refer to paths but no script that exists with the named "Path"

public class PutOnPathExample : MonoBehaviour{
 public Transform[] path;
 public float percentage;

Comment: You just showed some of your variable names from the script I don't think that will be enough to understand the error. Try to show the lines where the errors are occurring if possible like line 15, 59 etc.  written in the console.

Comment: Sure thing:

It seems it has anything to do with the reference "Path"

(15,59)
[HideInInspector] public string outputPath = Path.GetTempPath();

(98,36)
encodedFilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, GetFileName());

This when I import the vimeo unity package located here: [link]https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/releases

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the errors by adding "System.IO." in front of "Path" on the references throwing the errors. This caused all my errors to go away.